# Is there any difference in the way Python code is executed when run from REPL vs a script in the command line?

Tags: python

I was watching this video, [How Do You Read a Python Traceback?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCnMl.png) and they mention that the traceback you receive will be slightly different depending on whether you are executing your code in the command line (Fig. 1) vs in the REPL (Fig. 2). With the former, the executed lines of code are displayed in the traceback, whereas they are not in the later. What is the reason for this difference? Is there any difference in the way Python code is executed when run from REPL vs a script in the command line? Is the Python code compiled in both cases to bytecode?

```
def greet(someone):
    print('Hello', + someon)
    
greet('Chad')
```

[image]

Figure 1. Video example of code executed from command line displays executed lines of code

[image]
Figure 2. Video example of code executed from REPL does not display executed lines of code

Further confounding is that when executed from my Spyder IDE (which I would assume is an example of REPL capability), it unexpectedly mimics that of the command line output (Fig. 3).

[image]
Figure 3. My output from Spyder

Finally, when run from Bash on my computer it displays the additional text: "Did you mean: 'someone'?".
[image]
Figure 4. My output from Bash

Comment: Code should be provided as text, not screenshots. See https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: ...some differences are coming from Spyder because it's IPython, not the standard Python REPL. The standard REPL _does_ have some differences from how scripts are interpreted (specifically, about how blank lines are interpreted -- previously-answered questions about this in our knowledgebase are numerous), but IPython adds a lot more of them.

Comment: Anyhow, the difference between `File <stdin>` and `File somename` shouldn't be confounding at all: When you're typing into a repl, you _aren't_ typing into a file, so how _could_ it provide a filename? All it knows is that you typed something on stdin.

Comment: ...anyhow, "what's the difference between IPython and the standard REPL (or running a script without IPython)?" is far too broad to be answered in a Stack Overflow question. A good place to start would be reading the feature list at https://ipython.org/ -- literally everything it does for you is a change from standard baseline Python behavior.

Comment: The code is left as "someon" so that a traceback is called and to be able to see a traceback printed back differently between REPL and command line. The difference discussed is not standard input, but that the code executed is not included in the report.

Comment: That's easy. If the code's coming from a file, the line numbers can be referenced back to that file to look up the original source. By contrast, stdin is transient, unless you have something like IPython caching it for you. There's always a translation to an AST form before interpretation, so interpretation isn't happening directly on the source code; there's no reason to retain it in RAM.

Comment: ...btw, I did already recommend referring back to the IPython docs, right?